Empirical estimation of Wasserstein distance
I tried to estimate the Wasserstein distance of $d$-dimensional samples from the Gaussian distribution for $d\in\{1,2,5,10\}$. I got weird numbers so I did a sanity check of comparing two Gaussian distributions with the same mean and variance. Of course, the theoretical value of the Wasserstein distance is $0$, but my estimator strongly deviates from this in my toy example.
The output for the Wasserstein-1 distance is:
$$ dim=1: 0.0262, dim=2: 0.0917 ,dim=3: 0.2948, dim=5: 1.1009, dim=10: 4.2909 $$
and I get similar results for the Wasserstein-2 distance.
Does the estimation really work this badly in practice or am I doing something wrong?
My code is as follows:
import numpy as np
import ot

n=5000

for d in [1,2,3,5,10]:
    est=0
    true=0
    rep=20
    for r in np.arange(rep):

        mean=np.zeros(d)
        cov=np.eye(d)

        s1=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,size=n)
        s2=np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,size=n)

        m=ot.dist(s1, s2,metric='cityblock')
        a=np.ones(n)/n
        b=np.ones(n)/n
        
        wd=ot.emd2(a,b,m,numItermax=100000)
        est=est+wd/rep

    print("Dim=",d," est=",est)

